# Open Power Bi report in WPF

Tags: wpf, windows, powerbi, wpf-controls, powerbi-embedded

Thanks in advance,

I want to integrate Power Bi report in a WPF application without hosting it on power bi service or Azure.Can we do it.is there any control to open in the application.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, and no. Yes, you can embed a Power BI report in a WPF application (see [Integrate Power BI Dashboards, Reports and Tiles into a WPF Application](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/integrate-power-bi-dashboards-reports-and-tiles-into-a-wpf-application/)), but it must be published to Power BI service. No, you can't just parse the pbix file and render it with your code. You need Power BI service or Power BI Report Server to do that.